# Is copy automatic on assignment with matlab.mixins.Copyable

Tags: matlab, oop, handle

### Short-short version

Is it possible to get an handle to a subclass of `Copyable` rather than getting a copy?

---

### Context

I have a class hierarchy that i want to have `Copyable`.

```
classdef A < matlab.mixins.Copyable
    properties
        stuff;
    end

    methods
        function action(self)
            % ...
        end
    end
end
```

Various subclasses provide variations on the main behavior, and a particular subclass works to aggregate several of those behviors for sequenctial application

```
classdef multiA < classA
    properties
        nElements = 1;
        elements;
        iElement = 0;
        currentElement;
    end

    methods
        function self = multiA()
        end

        function addElement(self, fhdl)
            if self.nElements == 0
                self.nElements = 1;
                self.elements = {fhdl}; % Store handles to constructors
            else
                self.nElements = self.nElements + 1;
                self.elements(self.nElements) = fhdl; % Store handles to constructors
            end
        end

        function nextElement(self)
            if self.iElement < self.nElements
                self.iElement = self.iElement + 1;
                fhdl = self.elements(self.iElement);
                self.element = fhdl(); % instantiate with constructors
            end
        end

        function action(self)
            if self.iElement > 0 && self.iElement <= self.nElements
                self.currentElement.action(); % Pass use request to constructed objects
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The user is expected to build up objects with `addElement`, and work through the list with `nextElement` invoking the behavior of the contained objects as needed with `action.

```
multi = multiA();
multi.addElement( @OneSubClass );
multi.addElement( @AnotherSubClass );
multi.addElement( @ThirdSubClass );
% ...
multi.nextElement();
multi.action();
```

#### The problem emerges

The `multiA` class passes some basic unit tests and I started trying to apply it. And it seemed to be working. Then I get a situation where `multi.action()` seems to be flipping unpredictably back and forth between two behaviors.

It seems unlikely, but just conceivable that somehow the object of type `OneSubClass` is sticking around after I have moved on to `AnotherSubClass`.

#### The (wrong?) solution

Write a unit test which captures the handle of each element as it is instantiate and checks that this remains the handle in use until the next one is instantiated. Something like:

```
multiA.nextElement();
ehdl = multiA.currentElement;
% do things
testCase.veriftySameHandle(multiA.currentElement,ehdl);
```

Alas `ehdl` seems to be a *copy* of the stored element rather than a handle to it even though I have not explicitly invoked `copy()`. (I say that because `ehdl` retains the state of the contained object at the time of `nextElement()` while the fresh access of `currentElement` shows the expected changes.)

Is there a way to force the retention of a handle to an object derived from `matlab.mixins.Copyable`?

Comment: Should the third line in `nextElement` be this?: `self.currentElement = self.elements{self.iElement}();`

Comment: Yes. Of course. Well, I find it easier to read broken into two pieces, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: Is the code as it's shown above the *actual* code you are using. I can see a few errors that would appear to make it impossible for the code above to actually run.

Comment: No, that's an abstract I typed here. And matlab is not a langauge I've had much experience in until recently, so I'm still building the ability to see the correctness or lack thereof. Now that you mention it I can see tht I've left out at least 5(1) instance of `self.`.

Comment: @dmckee Have you [noticed](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eq.html) that "When comparing handle objects, use `==` to test whether objects have the same handle. Use `isequal` to determine if objects with different handles have equal property values." ?

Comment: @rahnema1 Well, I assume the authors of `matlab.unittest.TestCase` have. But the core issue here seems to revolve around `matlab.mixin.Copyable`. I had originally thought that it simply added the `copy()` method, but in the context of the unit tests it is acting like assignment is invoking the copy behavior instead of the usual handle behavior. So I am confuse. On the other hand, I have found a work around for my unit test and have moved on for now.